# Include a local "external" php/html file using php

Tags: php, include, centos

I'll try and word this as sensibly as possible.

I have two dedicated servers that are networked together with local IP's (10.1.2.1 / 10.1.2.2). Basically I need to be able to include files (php scripts/html/etc.) interchangeably from either server, but without the risk of allowing external scripts to be run.

Is this possible?

Running CentOS 5 on both servers with full root access.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want a fallback in case one server goes down? What?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear in my motive.  I'm running a CPU intensive web application on one server with the other dedicated to running a client backend.  However, I need to be able to include one specific aspect of the web application on the client server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both machines are networked, you could always create a virtual directory on the main web server that points to the network drive with the secondary PHP files.

Comment: Ahem, possible duplicate? *cough*

Comment: How do I do this?  Not sure if this is the same as the answer mentioned above, but it sounds more along the lines of what I need (not having to change the Include_path and such.

Comment: well, my advice is geared towards an IIS (windows) machine, but the principle is similar. What OS are you running?

Answer (score 3):

Why not mutually mount the other server's drive and set PHP's `include_path` ini-setting accordingly. This way you can safely include remote files without worrying about the usual attack vectors.

Comment: Ahem, possible duplicate? *cough*

Comment: Sounds like this might be the way to go.  Would this affect anything I currently have setup, performance or otherwise?

Comment: Network shares are in principal slower than own disk drives but if it's not for high performance and both server's are close to each other there shouldn't be any noticeable drawback.

Comment: Any decent guides out there for undertaking something like this?